# The ability to play several different music files in website

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of creating my own music player on the website. I have a problem that I don't know what to do so that I can play a few different songs from different divs. To be more specific, I mean that when you press the `button.play`, in the first `.audio-player` will play **music.mp3**. And after pressing the `button.play` in the second `.audio-player` will play **music1.mp3**.

```
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio src="music.mp3"></audio>
    <button class="play">play</button>
    <div class="seek-bar">
        <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio src="music1.mp3"></audio>
    <button class="play">play</button>
    <div class="seek-bar">
        <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('button.play');
var seekBar = document.querySelector('.seek-bar');
var fillBar = seekBar.querySelector('.fill');

var pointerdown = false;

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    if(pointerdown) return;

    var p = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;

    fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%';
});

function clamp (min, val, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(min, val), max);
}

function getP (e) {
    var p = (e.clientX - seekBar.offsetLeft) / seekBar.clientWidth;
    p = clamp(0, p, 1);

    return p;
}

seekBar.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(e){
    pointerdown = true;

    var p = getP(e);

    fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%';
});

window.addEventListener('pointermove', function(e){
    if(!pointerdown) return;

    var p = getP(e);

    fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%';
});
window.addEventListener('pointerup', function(e){
    if(!pointerdown) return;

    pointerdown = false;

    var p = getP(e);

    fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%';

    audio.currentTime = p * audio.duration;
});
```

Comment: @BadroNiaimi I just changed the content of my post. I think this is now better explained.

Answer (score 1):

> The `Document` method [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first `Element` within
>   the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
>   selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

You should use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) when you want to get all matching elements in the document.

Having said that, it can easily be done if you use [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)
.

Simple example based on your code:

```js
const players = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-player'),
      audio = new Audio();

players.forEach(player => {
    let playBtn = player.querySelector('.play');
    
    playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let currentAudio = player.querySelector('audio');
        
        document.querySelectorAll('.play').forEach(btn => {
            if (btn.textContent === 'Pause') {
                btn.textContent = 'Play';
            }
        });
        
        playToggle(currentAudio, playBtn);
    });
});

function playToggle(currentAudio, playBtn) {
    if (audio.src !== currentAudio.src) {
        audio.src = currentAudio.src;
        audio.play();
        playBtn.textContent = 'Pause';
        return;
    }
    
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        playBtn.textContent = 'Pause';
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        playBtn.textContent = 'Play';
    }   
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio src="https://www.free-stock-music.com/music/naoya-sakamata-dark-piano-music.mp3"></audio>
    <button class="play">Play</button>
    <div class="seek-bar">
        <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio src="https://www.free-stock-music.com/music/alexander-nakarada-wintersong.mp3"></audio>
    <button class="play">Play</button>
    <div class="seek-bar">
        <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```